# How to set up a sftp server on iOS

Tags: ios, sftp

In my project, I would like to set up an sftp server on my iOS device which may use the app sandbox directory as root. Not a client which can connect to a sftp server.

Is it allowed to do so? What I've found on the internet are sftp clients , nothing for a server on iOS.

If we are allowed, is there any library we can use?

If not, how may I build the server myself?

Comment: It's possible to use SSH/SFTP server components including in our SecureBlackbox library (C++ edition) in iOS. Not a trivial task and not a ready-to-deploy server, but the task is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an SFTP server written in C or C++.

There are lots of examples for these languages. e.g. [sftp-server.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-7.1/openssh/sftp-server.c)

You add the .c and .h file to the iOS project, you change the name of the main function to something else, you run the function formerly known as main in a separate thread (to liberate the main thread), and Bob's your uncle...